# ORA-00937: not a single-group group function how?

Tags: sql, oracle

How can I fix this error?

```
select r.quartiere,max(count(*))
from ristoranti r,prenotazioni p 
where p.data <'14'
 and p.data >'3' 
and r.codice=p.ristorante
group by r.quartiere
```

Comment: you are doing a double aggregate.

Comment: It depends. What were you trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `max(count(*))` you can't select `r.quartiere`

(but leave it in the GROUP BY)

```
select    max(count(*))
from      ristoranti r,prenotazioni p 
where     p.data <'14' and p.data >'3' and r.codice=p.ristorante
group by  r.quartiere
```

Answer (score 0):

Losing the `r.quartiere`, this should work.

```
select max(count(*))
from ristoranti r,prenotazioni p 
where p.data <'14' and p.data >'3' and r.codice=p.ristorante
group by r.quartiere;
```

This says select maximum of counts in each `quartiere`

Answer (score 0):

Asking for `MAX(COUNT(*))` doesn't make any sense. If you run the following

```
select r.quartiere, count(*)
  from ristoranti r,
       prenotazioni p
  where p.data <'14' and
        p.data >'3' and
        r.codice=p.ristorante
  group by r.quartiere
```

you'd get one row per `quartiere`. The count value you get IS the maximum count for each `quartiere` because there's only one count.

Hope this helps.